# How check the version of @angular/material in my system and the last version that exists of material

Tags: npm, version

I put this command: > npm ls @angular/material this command says me the last version in my system, but I also want the version that currently exists of material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
npm show @angular/material version
```

Or, if you want to see all available versions:

```
npm show @angular/material@* version
```